# Kotlin: How to write a function that returns a custom response for a task?

Tags: function, kotlin, callback, listener, response

I am kind of new on Kotlin interfaces and abstract classes and similar stuff. I want to find a smart way to create a function in a DifferentActivity that returns an object with custom responses back in the MainActivity, like the following:

```
fun myFunction(): CustomObjectResponse {
    try{
       /* Heavy work */
       return CustomObjectResponse.onFirstTypeSuccess(something)
    }
    catch(e: Exception){
       return CustomObjectResponse.onFail(some_other_thing)
    } 
}
```

So in case of success, it returns one kind of response with a parameter, in case of failure, it returns a different response with a different parameter.

And then, in my MainActivity I want to implement the two different responses in something like:

```
DifferentActivity.myFunction().onResponse( object: CustomObjectResponse(){
   override fun onFirstTypeSuccess(something: Any) {
        // do stuff
   }
   override fun onFail(some_other_thing: Any) {
        // do other stuff
   }
}
```

Can something like this be done without extending / implementing anything on the MainActivity/DifferentActivity classes themselves, only limited at function level?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ... you want something like this?

```
sealed class CustomObjectResponse
data class SuccessResponse(val x:X):CustomObjectResponse
data class FailResponse(val y:Y):CustomObjectResponse


fun myFunction(): CustomObjectResponse {
    try{
       /* Heavy work */
       return SuccessResponse(something)
    }
    catch(e: Exception){
       return FailResponse(some_other_thing)
    } 
}
```

and the MainActivity

```
fun handleResponse ( response: CustomObjectResponse ){
   when(response){
     is SuccessResponse ->  { 
       println( response.x) 
       //and do stuff 
     }
     is FailureResponse ->  { 
       println( response.y) 
       //and do other stuff 
     }
   }
}
```

??

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I want. Thank you!